# why is context undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**PROBLEM**

I am trying to make an alert dialog reusable via context API. however i get an error saying that context is undefined. I have defined my context and the dialog component as shown below;

```
const dialogContext = React.createContext();
const {Provider, Consumer} = dialogContext;

const C = {
  ask: 'ASK',
}

export function DialogProvider({children}){

  const [dialogState, setDialogState] = React.useState({
    show: false,
    message: '',
    type: C.ask,
    title: '',
    id: '',
  })

  return(
    <Provider value={{dialogState, setDialogState}}>
      {children}
    </Provider>
  )
}

export  function AlertDialogSlide({myPayload}) {
  const {warn, title, message, callback, id} = myPayload;
  const context =  React.useContext(dialogContext);
  console.log(context, dialogContext);

  const {dialogState ,setDialogState} = context;

  const open = (id) => {
    setDialogState({
      ...dialogState,
      show: true,
      message: message.description,
      title: message.title,
      id,
    })
  }

  if(warn){
    open(id)
  }

  const handleClose = (callBack, args=[]) => {
    console.log('arguments',args)
    callBack.fn && callBack.fn(...args);
    setDialogState({
      ...dialogState,
      show: false,
    })
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog
        open={dialogState.show}
        TransitionComponent={Transition}
        keepMounted
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-slide-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-slide-title">{title}</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-slide-description">
            {message}
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            No
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={() => handleClose(callback)} color="primary">
            Yes
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Using it my code looks like this

```
import {AlertDialogSlide, DialogProvider} from './Dialog';
...

...
  <DialogProvider>
    <AlertDialogSlide
      myPayload={payload}
    />
  </DialogProvider>
...
```

However,i get an error saying that context is undefined and i cannot destructure needed values from context

```
×
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'dialogState' of 'context' as it is undefined.
AlertDialogSlide
C:/Users/DESIGNHIVE II/Desktop/sellervasiti/src/components/Dialog.jsx:43
```

if there is a better way of doing this without the whole context thing i would like links to resources also.

Comment: you might need to pass a default value into your context * like `React.createContext({{)`

Comment: thanks Tom, however even after setting a default value it still doesn't update provider to use  ``<Provider value={{dialogState, setDialogState}}>
      {children}
    </Provider>``

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue...The code above is correct as regards the context definition and usage....the problem was somewhere else in the code, the dialog component was used without a provider. Thanks to all of you.